# How to convert this list to desired format in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
x = [[(u'reads_2.fq',)], [], [(u'README.txt',)]]
```

Desired output:

```
['reads.fq', 'README.txt']
```

Comment: Where did you run into problems while trying to do this?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a list comprehension:

```
>>> [a for b in x for c in b for a in c]
[u'reads_2.fq', u'README.txt']
```

Or if you're using Python 2.7 (note that the `compiler` module is deprecated, and is not available in python 3):

```
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>> flatten(x)
[u'reads_2.fq', u'README.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>> y = []
>>> for a in x:
...     if a:
...         y.append(a[0][0])
...
>>> y
[u'reads_2.fq', u'README.txt']
```